# What’s the standard way of showing phonemic inventory and orthography in the same table?

Tags: phonology, orthography

I’m describing the phonology of an Asian language. I put all the phonemes in a clear table. Since I use a local (Roman letter-based) orthography in my transcribed examples, I think it’d be handy to include the orthographic conventions in the same table, next to the phonemes.

What’s the standard way to do this? Use curly brackets for the orthography or is there some other practice?

Thanks!

Comment: I don' think you mean "phenomenal". "Phonemic"?

Comment: Autocorrect ... though you got to admit it sounds better

Answer (score 3):

The standard convention for indicating orthography is with angled brackets, thus [ jɛs ] / iɛs / < yes > (meaning respectively phonetically, phonemically or underlyingly, and orthographically).

Answer (score 3):

I would use angle-brackets ⟨like this⟩, next to the phonemes in the table.

For example, [taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkadian_language#Consonants):

[image: chart of Akkadian consonants]